# What's the difference between the fundamental group of an oriented graph and a non-oriented graph?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am trying to calculate the fundamental group of a hexagon with presentation $a^{-1}b^{-1}c^{-1}abc$. After identification it has only 2 vertices, then what should be its spanning tree? How to calculate its fundamental group?

Comment: Your question demonstrates some confusion. I assume you want to calculate the fundamental group of a hexagon (including its interior) with boundary glued together in the indicated pattern. This is not the same as finding the fundamental group of a graph.

Comment: In any event, the graph you get by looking at the boundary of the hexagon has two vertices and three edges which connect those vertices, labeled a,b,c. Then any edge will serve as a spanning tree, say the edge c. So the fundamental group of the graph will be a free group generated by $ac^{-1},bc^{-1}$.